# Question about the concept of $p$-conductivity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have a question related to the definition of the so called $p$-*conductivity*. My question is if **Definition 1** is equivalent to **Definition 2**:

**Definition 1.** Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open. Let $G \subset \Omega$ be open and bounded. Let $F \subset G$ be closed with the property $F \subset G \subset \overline{G} \subset \Omega$. The set $K = G \setminus F$ is called a *conductor*. For $p \geq 1$ we define the $p$-*conductivity* of $K$ as the number:

$$c_p(K):= \displaystyle \inf_{f \in \mathcal{C}} \displaystyle \int_{\Omega}\vert \nabla f \vert^p dx$$

where $\mathcal{C}$ is the class of locally Lipschitz functions (functions that satisfy a Lipschitz condition on arbitrary compacts of $\Omega$, i.e., $\vert f(x)-f(y)\vert \leq C_K\vert x - y\vert$ on the compact $K\subset \Omega$) with  the property $f \geq 1$ on $F$ and $f \leq 0$ on $\Omega \setminus G$.

**Definition 2.** Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open. Let $G \subset \Omega$ be open and bounded. Let $F \subset G$ be *relatively closed in $G$*. The set $K = G \setminus F$ is called a *conductor*. For $p \geq 1$ we define the $p$-*conductivity* of $K$ as the number:

$$c_p(K):= \displaystyle \inf_{f \in \mathcal{C}} \displaystyle \int_{\Omega}\vert \nabla f \vert^p dx$$

where $\mathcal{C}$ is taken as before.

---

Notice that in the second definition $F$ is not merely closed, but *relatively closed in* $\Omega$ and the condition $\overline{G} \subset \Omega$ is not imposed. It will be appreciated if you have any clue.